# I Can't Close/Dismiss Dialog

Tags: android

When I click the Save or Cancel button I want to dismiss this layout but I can't. dialog.dismiss or dialog.cancel won't work. When I click the save button it will work but after that with .close or .dismiss lines won't close the layout. Here are my codes.

```
    private Dialog getAddDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addLesson,null);


    Button save= (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    Button cancel= (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    final EditText answer = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et);
    final Spinner sp = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.sp);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lessons, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);


    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) layout.findViewById(R.id.dp);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add information");
    builder.setView(layout);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();



    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int day= datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                int month= datePicker.getMonth()+1;
                int year= datePicker.getYear();

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = df.parse(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long date= date.getTime();
                int position= sp.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String lesson= (String) sp.getItemAtPosition(position);

                int lessonNumber= Integer.valueOf(answer.getText().toString());

                Student student= new Student (lesson,lessonNumber,date);

                Database db = new Database (getApplicationContext());
                long id = db.AddInfo(student);

                if (id==-1){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                getList();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter the number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss(); // <-- DOESN'T WORK
        }
    });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss(); // <-- DOESN'T WORK

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line

```
builder.show();
```

For me by including this line, it was force closing the app. But after removing it, it was working fine and even the dialog got dismissed after clicking on the buttons. 
`Dialog` should be `show()` not a `Builder`